# Is, with $(x_n)$ a Markov chain, $(n,x_n)$ always a time homogeneous markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Someone told me that this discrete stochastic process $(n,x_n)$ is always a time homogeneous Markov chain (where $(x_n)$ is a discrete Markov chain).

What do you think of that proposition ? It seems false to me, because I don't see how adding $n$ to the process makes it T.H.

Otherwise, do you know how to transform any Markov chain into a time homogeneous one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every state in the new Markov chain has the time included in the state itself.  Therefore, the transition probabilities only depend on the states.

That's what makes it time-homogeneous, but in a rather brutish way.  For instance, it will turn a finite-state markov chain into an infinite-state markov chain, and every state in the new chain is transient because they can be visited at most once.

Comment: can you be please more precise about : " Therefore, the transition probabilities only depend on the states. " I think it is what I don't grasp yet

Comment: I understand your answer, it is true it is brutish, however I don't get how you proved that :
$$ P( y_{n+1} = (n+1, i) | y_n = (n, j) ) = P( y_{1} = (1, i) | y_0 = (0, j) )  $$ when $x_n$ is not itself a time homogenous Markov Chain

Comment: I am trying my best to understand. I think that $m$ and $n$ are the same, it isn't a dummy variable, $m$ is n but with another name right? I think you're totally right, and I haven't thought about having to redefine transition probabilities etc... however, I don't get why the RHS is time homogeneous. Don't you have to prove your math statement from 2 comments above ? ( $P(x_{n+1} = x | x_n = y ) = P(x_1 = z | x_0 = w ) $, especially when $x = z$, $y = w$). Sorry to insist, I really try to understand the core of the statement

Comment: I have to assume at this point that there's a language barrier.  Let me summarize more concisely, and then I'm going to delete the above comments, since they'll become redundant:

Comment: First: Assuming $x_n$ is a Markov chain with state space $X$, it seems the only reasonable way to define $y_n$ is as a Markov chain with state space $\mathbb{N} \times X$ with the transition probabilities $$P(y_{n+1} = (m_1, i) \mid y_n = (m_2, j)) = \begin{cases}P(x_{m_1}=i \mid x_{m_2} = j) & \text{ if } m_1 = m_2+1 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: With this definition, we have $$\begin{align*}P(y_{n+1}=(m_1,i) \mid y_n = (m_2,j)) &= \begin{cases}P(x_{m_1}=i \mid x_{m_2}=j) & \text{ if } m_1 = m_2 +1 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases} \\ &= P(y_1 = (m_1,i) \mid y_0 = (m_2, j))\end{align*}$$ Therefore $y_n$ is a time-homogeneous Markov chain.

Comment: In particular, note that $m$ in my previous post and $m_1, m_2$ here need not be related to $n$ in any way.  Also, my comment regarding $P(x_{n+1}=x\mid x_n=y) = P(x_1 = z\mid x_0 = w)$ was to point out that this should be false for general states $x,y,z,w$ but this doesn't imply $x_n$ isn't time-homogeneous.  We require $x=z$ and $y=w$ in the definition, and in your comment, you had $(n+1,i), (n,j), (1,i), (0,j)$ which are four distinct states for the Markov chain $y_n$

Comment: thank you @Brian, for your time and patience. I now understand.